# Word Ifilter installed on Windows 2k3 Server?

Tags: windows, ms-word, windows-server-2003, ifilter

Does anyone know if the iFilters for MS Word are installed by default on a vanilla Win 2k3 server?

Answer (score 0):

IFilter Explorer will tell you what IFilters you have installed. This will probably tell you what you need: http://www.citeknet.com/Products/IFilters/IFilterExplorer/tabid/62/Default.aspx

There is an IFilter blog that should be able to answer all your questions, but StackOverflow will only let me post one link!

From my personal experience, I believe if you install Index Server or SharePoint Services, they will come with IFilters for MSOffice 2003 files. I don't recall having to install anything special for them.

Answer (score 0):

They are not installed. But you can get them here without the need for a full office:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20109

regards,
Jimmy